# Tensorflow Interpreter throwing error for "data count" iOS

Tags: ios, swift, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am using TensorFlowLiteSwift and the model I'm working with is responsible for flattening an image when the image is cropped in a trapezoidal shape.
Now, Tensorflow does not provide much of a documentation. So, I have been trying to implement things from their example projects.
But here is the catch, it throws error saying "Provided data count must match the required count" and the required count is 4. I backtracked the `byteCount` in Interpreter.swift but could not find the actual setter.
**So, is the `.tflite` model responsible for the "required count?" And if no, then how does this get set?**

Here is a chunk of code I think would help understanding my problem:

```
/// Performs image preprocessing, invokes the `Interpreter`, and processes the inference results.
    func runModel(on item: ImageProcessInfo) -> UIImage? {
        let rgbData = item.resizedImage.scaledData(with: CGSize(width: 1000, height: 900),
                                                   byteCount: inputWidth * inputHeight
                                                   * batchSize,
                                                   isQuantized: false)
        
        var corner = item.corners.map { $0.map { p -> (Float, Float) in
            return (Float(p.x), Float(p.y))
            } }
        var item = item
        
        guard let height = NSMutableData(capacity: 0) else { return nil }
        height.append(&item.originalHeight, length: 4)
        
        guard let width = NSMutableData(capacity: 0) else { return nil }
        width.append(&item.originalWidth, length: 4)
        
        guard let corners = NSMutableData(capacity: 0) else { return nil }
        corners.append(&corner, length: 4)
        
        do {
            try interpreter.copy(rgbData!, toInputAt: 0)
            try interpreter.copy(height as Data, toInputAt: 1)
            try interpreter.copy(width as Data, toInputAt: 2)
            try interpreter.copy(corners as Data, toInputAt: 3)
            try interpreter.invoke()
            
            let outputTensor1 = try self.interpreter.output(at: 0)
            
            guard let cgImage = postprocessImageData(data: outputTensor1.data, size: CGSize(width: 1000, height: 900)) else {
                return nil
            }
            
            let outputImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
            return outputImage
            
        } catch {
            dump(error)
            return nil
        }
    }

extension UIImage {
    func scaledData(with size: CGSize, byteCount: Int, isQuantized: Bool) -> Data? {
      guard let cgImage = self.cgImage, cgImage.width > 0, cgImage.height > 0 else { return nil }
      guard let imageData = imageData(from: cgImage, with: size) else { return nil }
      var scaledBytes = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: byteCount)
      var index = 0
      for component in imageData.enumerated() {
        let offset = component.offset
        let isAlphaComponent = (offset % 4)
          == 3
        guard !isAlphaComponent else { continue }
        scaledBytes[index] = component.element
        index += 1
      }
      if isQuantized { return Data(scaledBytes) }
      let scaledFloats = scaledBytes.map { (Float32($0) - 127.5) / 127.5 }
      return Data(copyingBufferOf: scaledFloats)
    }

private func imageData(from cgImage: CGImage, with size: CGSize) -> Data? {
      let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(
        rawValue: CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Big.rawValue | CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue
      )
      let width = Int(size.width)
      let scaledBytesPerRow = (cgImage.bytesPerRow / cgImage.width) * width
      guard let context = CGContext(
          data: nil,
          width: width,
          height: Int(size.height),
          bitsPerComponent: cgImage.bitsPerComponent,
          bytesPerRow: scaledBytesPerRow,
          space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
          bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue)
      else {
        return nil
      }
      context.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
      return context.makeImage()?.dataProvider?.data as Data?
    }
}

@discardableResult
  public func copy(_ data: Data, toInputAt index: Int) throws -> Tensor {
    let maxIndex = inputTensorCount - 1
    guard case 0...maxIndex = index else {
      throw InterpreterError.invalidTensorIndex(index: index, maxIndex: maxIndex)
    }
    guard let cTensor = TfLiteInterpreterGetInputTensor(cInterpreter, Int32(index)) else {
      throw InterpreterError.allocateTensorsRequired
    }

    /* Error here */
    let byteCount = TfLiteTensorByteSize(cTensor)
    guard data.count == byteCount else {
      throw InterpreterError.invalidTensorDataCount(provided: data.count, required: byteCount)
    }

    #if swift(>=5.0)
      let status = data.withUnsafeBytes {
        TfLiteTensorCopyFromBuffer(cTensor, $0.baseAddress, data.count)
      }
    #else
      let status = data.withUnsafeBytes { TfLiteTensorCopyFromBuffer(cTensor, $0, data.count) }
    #endif  // swift(>=5.0)
    guard status == kTfLiteOk else { throw InterpreterError.failedToCopyDataToInputTensor }
    return try input(at: index)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

What are the input shapes? Can you identify which one is complaining about the size?

At the first glance, `corners.append(&corner, length: 4)` seems weird - does `corners` contain only 1 `Float` (byte size 4)?

The `byteCount` for a tensor is filled by underlying C API, and simply returns `tensor->bytes` for underlying `TfLiteTensor` struct that is filled in the model loading stage.

Comment: It's resolved. I was converting the image to data in completely wrong way. Tensorflow example projects helped me. Sad that iOS doesn't have documentations yet. Hoping to get guides soon. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @KoushikMudi Can you further share the Tensorflow example which helped here? I have the same question